# Move worksheet with partial name

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple excel files with date(xxx_191216) in a folder (191216).

Each file consist of 2 worksheets:

Worksheet 1 Name: xxxx_tData which tData is being used n every file
Woeksheet 2 Name: yyyy_Report which Report is being used in every file too.

Now, I need to move "report" worksheet as the First worksheet instead of "tData".

I have to do this for all my files in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet can be moved with a simple method :

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Move after:=Worksheets("Sheet2") 
'before or after depends of your needs
```

in your case I think :

```
Worksheets("report").Move before:=Worksheets("tData")
```